# Unable to suppress UserWarning returned by interpret

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I am using [interpret](https://pypi.org/project/interpret/) for a project, and during the tests I provide to few samples (just to speed up tests) which results in a UserWarning

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/interpret/glassbox/ebm/utils.py:91: UserWarning: Too few samples per class, adapting test size to guarantee 1 sample per class.
  warnings.warn(
```

I have been trying to suppress this warning so far with no success, I have even tried using a carte blanch `ignore::UserWarning` in my pytest filterwarnings, as follows:

```
[tool:pytest]
addopts = -s --maxfail=1 --failed-first --color=yes
filterwarnings = ignore::_pytest.warning_types.PytestUnknownMarkWarning
                 ignore::UserWarning
                 ;ignore::UserWarning:interpret
norecursedirs = docs .mypy_cache
python_files = test_*.py
```

I have delved in to the file that threw the warning, where the actual lines that throw the warning are as follows:

```
if n_test_samples < y_uniq:  # pragma: no cover
    warnings.warn(
        "Too few samples per class, adapting test size to guarantee 1 sample per class."
    )
    test_size = y_uniq
```

which should be a `UserWarning`, as that's the default for [warnings.warn](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html). The question then is, **how would one suppress such a warning** as what I have used previously doesn't work for this case (in the pytest config)?

Here is an as isolated as possible example of the above listed problem (using the `mark` option to mimic our setup):

```
from interpret.glassbox import ExplainableBoostingClassifier
from numpy import array, ravel
from pytest import mark


@mark.filterwarnings("ignore::UserWarning")
def test():
    features = array([
        [0.4, 0.6, 0.8],
        [0.3, 0.7, 0.9],
        [0.1, 0.5, 1.1],
        [0.2, 0.8, 1.0],
        [0.2, 6.4, 1.2],
        [0.5, 8.6, 0.9],
        [0.5, 7.9, 0.7],
        [0.4, 7.5, 0.9],
    ])
    labels = ravel(array([
        ["class_1"],
        ["class_1"],
        ["class_1"],
        ["class_1"],
        ["class_2"],
        ["class_2"],
        ["class_2"],
        ["class_2"],
    ]))

    model = ExplainableBoostingClassifier()
    model.fit(X=features, y=labels)

# call funcy, should be done through pytest though
test()
```

Comment: Have you checked the code in `interpret` that issues the warning? You should see what kind of warning is created there.

Comment: I have, but in the wrong place, adjusting question accordingly

Comment: Your configuration seems to be in `setup.cfg`, correct? I know that it works in `pytest.ini` - maybe it is easier to configure this in `pytest.ini`? From the pytest help: `Usage of setup.cfg is not recommended unless for very simple use cases. .cfg files use a different
parser than pytest.ini and tox.ini which might cause hard to track down problems.`

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your problem is that you have a `pytest.ini` or `tox.ini` that is read by pytest. If any of these files exist in your path and contains a `[pytest]` section, this supersedes the `[tool:pytest]` section of `setup.cfg`. So the solution is either to remove the `pytest.ini` / `tox.ini`, or to move the `filterwarnings` line into `pytest.ini`:

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings = ignore::UserWarning:interpret
```

As mentioned in the comments, the [pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/customize.html#setup-cfg) states:

> Usage of setup.cfg is not recommended unless for very simple use cases. .cfg files use a different
> parser than pytest.ini and tox.ini which might cause hard to track down problems.

So the second option is probably the better one.

Comment: The project has indeed recently switched to Tox, so being pointed to that certainly is helpful. However, adding the `ignore::UserWarning:interpret` to the tox still yields the same results (which might be related to peripheral aspects such as the docker, make, etc. that I will look into now).

Comment: Maybe `interpret` is not the module where the warning originates, but rather a submodule - I haven't checked this. I would try to disable all user warnings first (as you did in your question) to be sure that this is not the problem.

Comment: That is one of the steps I tried after you answer, just blanket suppression of all UserWarnings in both the `tox.ini` and both of the `setup.cfg` files (that are used inside services, spun up as part of the project). Hence, I now fear it's project setup related, which would be out of my control.

Comment: As a last test, you could try to put a `pytest.ini` into the root dir where you add the supression, if that is possible. Other than that, I have no further idea (well, you could do the suppression in the pytest command line, but this is probably out of your control).